# Add Button at Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminform

I have a custom module for generate random keys. The concept is when admin clicks the add new button it will automatically creates the random codes, at the time of editing i have removed all buttons and added extra field button to send mail. Upto this i have no problem, but at the time of clicking send mail button i am facing problem,

I have written some scripts for onclick event,
Edit/Tab/Form.php:

```
$fieldset->addField('promo_email', 'text', array(
                            'label' => Mage::helper('promogenerator')->__('Send Mail'),
                            'name'  => 'promo_email',
                            'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="sendmail()">Send Mail</button>' 
                        ));
```

I have written the scripts at,
Edit.php:

```
$this->_formScripts[] = "

    function sendmail(){
        var email = jQuery('#promo_email').val(),
        code = jQuery('#promocode').val();
        window.location.href = '{$this->getUrl(`*/*/send`, array(`id` => $this->getRequest()->getParam(`id`)))}';
    }
";
```

the problem is in url, the script function not redirect me to the send url, it redirects me to the index page.

I really don't know how to give the url in scripts. Can someone point me the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$this->getUrl` try using

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl(....);
```

**[EDIT]**
Change your `formScripts` to this

```
$this->_formScripts[] = "

    function sendmail(){
        var email = jQuery('#promo_email').val(),
        code = jQuery('#promocode').val();
        window.location.href = '".$this->getUrl(`*/*/send`, array(`id` => $this->getRequest()->getParam(`id`)))."';
    }
";
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius. but it is redirect me to `promogenerator/edit/id/5/key/3420826223a1e7a36245f1c9649bdd91/%7BMage::helper(%60adminhtml%60)->getUrl(%60*/*/send%60,%20array(%60id%60%20=>%20()->getParam(%60id%60)))%7D`

Comment: @Astro See my update.

Comment: I am getting page not found error.. but i have `sendAction` function at my controller.

Comment: Try debugging step by step.  I got it to redirect properly. That's all I could do for now.

Comment: the error in single quotes, its working fine after correcting the quotes `window.location.href = '".$this->getUrl('*/*/send', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')))."';`